# Create data files in pip3 editable install mode

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install python package in editable mode with:

```
pip3 install -e ./
```

`setup.py` file contains:

```
data_files=[
    (os.path.expanduser("~") + "/.xxx", ["xxx/yyy.data"])
],
```

After installation the `yyy.data` file is not copied to `.xxx` folder.

Is there an option to create data files outside of the package folder when working in editable mode?

Comment: Which pip version do you use?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost pip 9.0.1 with Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 2):

The truth is *data_files* has caveats. See [No single, complete solution for packaging data](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/79) issue on the list of *Problems in Python Packaging*, note in [*data_files*](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#data-files) section of *Packaging and Distributing Project* tutorial from *Python Packaging User Guide*, pip's bug [*All packages that contain non-package data are now likely installed in a broken way since 7.0.0*](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2874) and wheel's bug [*bdist_wheel makes absolute data_files relative to site-packages*](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/issues/92).

According to information gathered from above sources your data was installed into *site-packages* directory instead of your home directory as you were expecting.